# dmesg constantly prints message "event field not found"?

Tags: kernel, error-handling, input-devices, dmesg, events

I have recently followed a guide that recommended to check dmesg for some output with `dmesg | grep something`. I forgot to add the grep-command first and just entered `dmesg` in the terminal, which resulted in the following message being printed over and over with different time stamps(?):

> [  xxx.xxxxxx] input input9: event field not found

There is no other output until the command terminates, only a wall of these "event field not found"-messages.

I have also noticed that some output that I am able to get from dmesg won't be accessible with the above command after some minutes. I don't know if this is normal behaviour or not, but I attributed it to the event field-messages filling up the log and removing the older entries, if that makes sense. There are some messages I can only access right after boot time.

Is this something to worry about and what could cause this?

Comment: Could you consider adding the contents of the file created by running `timeout  --signal=KILL 3s dmesg >> $(mktemp dmesg.XXXXXXXXXX)`. The file can be found by looking in the terminals current directory for a file with a name similar to `dmesg.XXXXXXXXXX` with the X's replaced by random characters.

Comment: Hey J. Starnes, sure. I created the file, but I don't know how to share it best. So, I've looked through the contents and there are 2977 lines of these `input input9: event field not found` messages with various numbers in the brackets from `[  495.200509]` to `[  848.656582]`, nothing else.

Comment: The numbers in square brackets are time codes since boot. You could [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/984220/edit) your question to include some or all of the output in a code box. See [editing-help](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help). Alternatively you could post the output via a site like [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/). dmesg usually has additional info about the error or at least a clue to what device is associated with input9. Right now my wild guess is that a keyboard/mouse device is sending malformed input.

Comment: Your assumption seems to be correct. I noticed that the messages stop as soon as I unplug my mouse. They don't start immediately when plugging it back in, but as soon as I move the mouse pointer, it seems. But from what I can tell the mouse is working fine and the system also correctly displays it in the settings (although it's in there twice). Should I worry about this or can the messages be ignored as long as I don't notice any hardware errors?